# look for multiple words within a string

Tags: php

I would like to search for multiple words within a string. I currently have the following condition. This seems very clunky and ugly. Is there a nicer way of doing it?

```
if (isset($myVar) && $myVar && strpos($myVar, 'foo') === false && strpos($myVar, 'bar') === false && strpos($myVar, 'steve') === false && strpos($myVar, 'one') === false && strpos($myVar, 'jobs') === false && strpos($myVar, 'dog') === false && strpos($myVar, 'blue') === false && strpos($myVar, 'cloud') === false && strpos($myVar, 'apple') === false)
    {

    // words do not exists in string

    }
  else
    {

    // words do not exists in string

    }
```

Comment: Build an array of the search terms then loop through it

Answer (score 1):

Just like @j08691 said, build an array of the search terms then loop through it.

```
<?php

    $words = array ( 'foo', 'bar', 'steve' );
    $x=0;

    do {

        $found = strpos($myVar, $words[$x]);
        $x++;

    } while ($found !== false);


    if ($found !== false) {
        echo 'has all';
    }
    else {
        echo 'words do not exists in string';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Strategy 1, using a loop:

You can iterate over an array containing all the words, and do a [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) one by one. This Is essentially the same as your current solution, but is less tedious if you have a lot of words and way easier to maintain and extend with more words.

```
$words = array('foo', 'bar', 'steve', 'one', 'jobs', 'dog', 'blue', 'cloud', 'apple');
$match = false;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($myVar, $word) !== false) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($match) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

You could break this out to a generic function for reuse

```
function str_contains($haystack, $needles, $mode = 'or') {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strpos($myVar, $word) !== false) {
            if ($mode == 'or') {
               return true;
            }
        } else {
            if ($mode == 'and') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $mode == 'or' ? false : true;
}

$words = array(...);
if (str_contains($myVar, $words)) {
    // one of your words are included
} else {
   // none of your words are included
}
if (str_contains($myVar, $words, 'and')) {
    // all of your words are included
} else {
    // at least one of your words are not included
}
```

### Strategy 2, using a regular expression:

Alternatively, you could create a regular expression and do this with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$words = array('foo', 'bar', 'steve', 'one', 'jobs', 'dog', 'blue', 'cloud', 'apple');
if (preg_match('/(' . implode('|', $words) . ')/', $myVar)) {
    // match
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `preg_match()` and pass the words as literal regex, like this

```
    if (isset($myVar) && $myVar && (preg_mach("(foo|bar|fooo)", $myVar) === 1)) {
//do somthing
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$words_to_search = ["wordA", "wordB", "wordC"];
foreach($words_to_search as $word){
    if(strpos($myVar, "$word"){
        //Exists
    } else{
        //Doesn't
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match :

```
 if(preg_match('(bad|naughty)', $data) === 1) {
//TO DO
  }
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function to check if some content from an array is found within another array.

```
$words = ['foo', 'bar', 'steve'];

if (array_intersect($words, explode(' ', $myVar))) {
    // Exists
}
```